# NavBar not going in the last position after i search

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a SearchBar and after i get the results i want to exit from the navbar by using the "X" icon or the "Back" key of the emulator but the navbar doesn't go to the last position
How can i fix it ?

screenshot from the app problem -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWxsE.jpg

Some code that i use to clear the state

public void getText(final View view)
    {

```
    final SearchView sv = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if(query.length() >= 1){
                userInput = query;
                fetchData();

                setAdapter(view);
                sv.clearFocus();

                view.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            setUpView(view);
            observeDataChange();
            setAdapter(view);

            sv.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(newText.length() >= 1){
                userInput = newText;
                fetchData();

                setAdapter(view);
                //sv.clearFocus();

                view.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your activity_main.xml file code by below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and fragment_dashboard.xml by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_of_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```